# VideoCastManager crashes after failing on FetchBitmapTask

Tags: android, google-cast

While the app is receiving metadata updates, VideoCastManager will begin repeatedly posting the following error, eventually crashing..
Our receiver sends metadata updates every second while ads are playing. This is how the SDK implements it and there's not much we can do about it.
I'm looking for a way to suppress this error w/o having to provide my own implementation of VideoCastManager.

Any ideas?

```
   java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:132)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:349)
       at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:149)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:295)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
       at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.utils.FetchBitmapTask.doInBackground(FetchBitmapTask.java:117)
       at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.utils.FetchBitmapTask.doInBackground(FetchBitmapTask.java:39)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The offending code seems to be here:

```
 private void updateMediaSessionMetadata() {
              ...

                  Uri iconUri = mm.hasImages() ? mm.getImages().get(0).getUrl() : null;
                  if (iconUri == null) {
                      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                              mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.album_art_placeholder);
                      mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(newBuilder
                              .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, bm)
                              .build());
                  } else {
                      if (mMediaSessionIconFetchTask != null) {
                          mMediaSessionIconFetchTask.cancel(true);
                      }
                      mMediaSessionIconFetchTask = new FetchBitmapTask() {
                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                              if (mMediaSessionCompat != null) {
                                  MediaMetadataCompat currentMetadata = mMediaSessionCompat
                                          .getController().getMetadata();
                                  MediaMetadataCompat.Builder newBuilder = currentMetadata == null
                                          ? new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                                          : new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder(currentMetadata);
                                  mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(newBuilder.putBitmap(
                                          MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, bitmap).build());
                              }
                              mMediaSessionIconFetchTask = null;
                          }
                      };
                      mMediaSessionIconFetchTask.execute(iconUri);
                  }

              ...
          }
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to send an update every second; where in the SDK it does a similar thing?

Comment: we don't really have control over that. It's what the mDialog sdk for chromecast does, when an ad is playing

Comment: Which is "mDoalog sdk for Chromecast"?